# Playing videos within cordova App on Windows Phone 8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, video, media, offline

Is there a way to get Windows phone 8 to play videos using phonegap?  I am looking to add videos to my App within so that to play them on the device.  It works right off the bat with iOS and I was able to use a plugin that enabled me to play videos on android devices.  However I've had no luck getting videos to play on Windows Phone 8 or find any plugins/information at all of anyone trying to play videos stored within the application on Windows Phone 8.

Are there any plugins/tricks/suggestions to get videos from within the phonegap app to play?

Comment: [This](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/020f8f/windows-phone-8-app-development-using-phonegap-cordova-par/) might help you.